# how can i add custom statusbar in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

we can add **custom **statusbar**** in **flex 3** by using below code.

`<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
showStatusBar="true"
statusBarFactory="{new ClassFactory(AppStatusBar)}">`

How can i add **custom statusbar** in **flex 4**..??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then you could use the controlBarContent in Flex4. E.g:

```
<s:controlBarContent>
[YOUR CODE]
[EXAMPLE]
<s:Label width="164" text="Welcome: {user.givenName} {user.familyName}"/>
........        
</s:controlBarContent>
```

You can read more about repositioning the controlBar [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/10/19/repositioning-the-control-bar-on-a-spark-panel-container-in-flex-4/).